# Django views opens different content

Tags: html, django, url, view, django-views

I am new to Django. I have created 2 seperate views and URLs, however, when I load my development server and click on slides to open slides_detail.html, it opens sub_detail.html, at this point I have no clue what could cause that as there are no similar names which would lead to opening completely different detail page. Both slides and subcontent sits in the same HTML document, same with URLs and views. There are no errors, to show. Thanks in advance:

URLS:

```
    path('<int:sub_id>/', views.sub_detail, name='sub_detail'),
    path('<int:slides_id>/', views.slides_detail, name='slides_detail'),
```

Views:

```
    # Will show specific sub content details
    def sub_detail(request, sub_id):
       subcontent = get_object_or_404(SubContent, pk=sub_id)
       context = {
        'subcontent': subcontent,
       }
    return render(request, 'home/sub_detail.html', context)


    # Will show specific slides content details
    def slides_detail(request, slides_id):
       slides = Slides.objects.get(pk=slides_id)
       context = {
        'slides': slides,
       }
    return render(request, 'home/slides_detail.html', context)
```

HTML for slides:

```
                     {% for slides in slides %}
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="card">
                            <a href="{% url 'slides_detail' slides.id %}">
                            <img src="{{ slides.image.url }}" class="card-img-top img-height" alt="..."></a>
                            <div class="card-body bg-dark">
                                
                                <h5 class="card-title text-light font-weight-bold text-center">{{ slides.title }}</h5>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

HTML for subcontent:

```
      {% for sub in subcontent %}
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
        <div class="row">
            {% if sub.image %}
                <div class="col-md-6 section-index-img">
                    <img src="{{ sub.image.url }}" class="rounded img-fluid" alt=""/>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href="{% url 'sub_detail' sub.id %}">
                <h4>{{ sub.title }}</h4>
            </a>
                <p class="text-muted">{{ sub.description | linebreaks }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% else %}
```

Comment: The templates overlap, so the path `/2` will trigger the first view that matches, in this case the `sub_detail`.

Comment: do I need to change a view or URL for that?

Comment: You need to prefix or suffix each url with something unique so it _only_ matches the one case you want. If you havea  record for `sub_id == 1` and one for `slide_id == 1`, then url `/1/` is going to match the first one in the list. Call these `/sub/<int:pk>/` and `/slide/<int:pk>/` instead, and the problem goes away.

Comment: Thank you, but when I do that it gives me 404, however, when I remove first / from /sub/<int:pk>/, leaving sub/<int:pk>/ it works perfectly. Once again, thank you. Do you know how I can find documentation for this to learn more?

Answer (score 2):

> I have created 2 *seperate* views and URLs, however, when I load my development server and click on slides to open `slides_detail.html`, it opens `sub_detail.html`.

You did not create two *separate* URLs, you created the same path. Both paths will fire on the same patterns. This thus means that if you have a `{% url 'slides_detail' 42 %}`, for example, it will be written as `/42`, but this is also a valid path for the `sub_detail`, so when you make a request with that path, Django will "*fire*" the first view that matches, in this case `sub_detail`.

You should make the paths non-overlapping, for example:

```
path('sub/<int:sub_id>/', views.sub_detail, name='sub_detail'),
path('slide/<int:slides_id>/', views.slides_detail, name='slides_detail'),
```